# I'm expecting to receive an array of objects from an API response but getting an array of Promises in React with TypeScript

Tags: typescript, api, async-await, promise, response

*I'm really sorry if this is a silly question for you. I'm kind of new to TypeScript and Promises thing. I tried to look for this solution at different sites but couldn't find anything relevent. Could you please help with how to receive an array of objects instead of promises. Also I'll be very thankful if you share some resources where I could find things related to React with TypeScript. Thanks in Advance!*

**index.ts**

```
    interface IFetchLikes {
      item_id: string;
      likes: number;
    }

const fetchLikes = async (): Promise<IFetchLikes[]> => {
    const response = await axios.get<IFetchLikes[]>('https://us-central1-involvement-api.cloudfunctions.net/capstoneApi/apps/PmGqiCAY4CG3PZPHNcEG/likes');
    return response.data;
  };

  console.log('Response: ', fetchLikes());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can not return IFetchLikes[] from `fetchLikes`  without promise.

Reason: Promises are used to make async code run synchronously. It is asynchronous because it has to wait for axios API to return data.

There are two ways to proceed with this information.

1. Either move the next calling function/ executable code after await. [TS example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/AQkSwOwFwUwJwGYEMDGNgEkBiMooBYAyYA1jAM7ADeAsAFCiOhiwC2A%20mACYBcw5UOJADmAbnpMmAG1IU%20EAK6sARvHENJwAL4TQKAPYQBwLEjIBBAB5h95AMJIpU4AF4QScgE8IKYAAoASmA%20YAAFOH1WMHIYAB4qYC4kKCRgzBw8IllyAG0AXW1gAD5XEqQAdyQWMIiomIA6OAp9KQA3GD8qJJS%20HKoWGA5uPgBycnIRgBpgGTJyPgAmbQLtAPVGXRADIyhgBFwCYjnXYA9vX0C%20cMjouOwDrLn8kpcS2g1JbeMm8gAHQxiJ1OlWqpgs1lsDicgWAAHpYUgIeR6sJcLF7pkjhRnn4RvgoFBfvN4QpyABaNDQOCOACMZMgrRa7VYMGgZKQvzA9RQUn0Ci4CAUPigNiM9QguFhKA5AkMMHMnIRvyJsNCrAA4gBHMB2cwATQALHZ1QBmUIALVCAAkAHIoACi6thswoIzWm0Y8OAcCFEBEwAlll2MEsaBQChSyik6AMXHQSAQsDgwBBUHqHo2HyYXxaMHqvOEuIAShR-kYYKNpj8yw1uql3VnGE0oAo4BBvaWAXm66I4bCA-pysBPHzEoZdhKYFxgFB9B2W23gGAEMPR1xxymkNAM9p1B79pjsoF1qAgA)
2. Use `then` to run code after premise has returned value. [TS example](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#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)

For documentation: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/react.html

Comment: How can I get only data ( array of objects ) and not promises? @vaira

Comment: My mistake i have updated the answer